# How to stop a Dynamic[] in one notebook from hurting performance in another?

Tags: front-end, dynamic

I have two notebooks open, one has a dynamic expression running (a simple clock)

```
Dynamic[{d, h, m, s} = 
  List @@ DateDifference[Now, 
     DateObject[{2015, 5, 18}], {"Day", "Hour", "Minute", 
      "Second"}][[1]];
   Grid[Transpose @ {{"d", d}, {"h", h}, {"m", m}, {"s", Round@s}}, 
       Alignment -> Left], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

And while this is running, it interferes strongly with the `Dynamic` expression in my other notebook, even when the notebook is offscreen or minimized. ***Is there any safeguard for these dynamics bringing the frontend to a crawl?***

Comment: Launch the notebooks in separate kernels running on separate cores (assuming you have a multi-core machine) with `LaunchKernels[2]`.

Comment: Wrap both dynamic expressions with DynamicModule and localize your variables there.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork What is the relation between kernels and dynamics, I thought that for Dynamic's the FE was the bottleneck.

Comment: @M.R.  A Dynamic's front end may or may not be the computational bottleneck, depending upon the algorithms, the complexity of the rendering, and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider moving the variables used for the dynamic clock into a dedicated context

```
Dynamic[{clock`d, clock`h, clock`m, clock`s} = 
  List @@ DateDifference[Now, 
     DateObject[{2015, 5, 18}], {"Day", "Hour", "Minute", 
      "Second"}][[1]];

Grid[Transpose@{{"d", clock`d}, {"h", clock`h}, {"m", clock`m}, {"s",
      Round@clock`s}}, Alignment -> Left], UpdateInterval -> 1]
```

When creating a variable by indicating a new context in the form  `` context`variable ``
 a new context will be created along with the variable. This can be verified using `Contexts[]`

Comment: @Karsten 7 thx for the formatting,,,,penguins not very smart :)